# Count tallying in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to tally the number of votes for a particular ideal temperature but I'm struggling with displaying the results. I can get it to give me a number of asterics equal to the temp, and I'm able to get it to give me one asteric per result but not to tally all of the votes. My instinct tells me I'm missing something super simple in displayData() but I'm too fried to spot it.

```
public void displayData() {
    String dots = "";
    System.out.println("------------------ Ideal Temperature Data --------------------");
    for (int numTemps = 0; numTemps < tempCounts.length; numTemps++) {
        if (tempCounts[numTemps] != 0) {
            dots += "*";
            System.out.println(numTemps + "  : " + dots);
        }
        dots = "";
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

output is currently:

```
     ------------------ Ideal Temperature Data --------------------
     63  : *
     65  : *
     68  : *
     69  : *
     70  : *
     72  : *
     75  : *
     ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

output should be:

```
     ------------------ Ideal Temperature Data --------------------
     63  : *
     65  : **
     68  : *****
     69  : ***
     70  : *
     72  : ***
     75  : **
     ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How is the number of dots determined? How do you know 63 should have 1 dot and 68 should have 5?

Comment: @Bohemian I have an array of the numbers of each vote. If you voted for 68, then the integer "68" is added to an array that I'm cycling through to count the votes. I can get it so spit out how many votes each number has numerically, but cannot get it to spit out the number of asterisks instead

Comment: In that case your data structure is incorrect.  Either you need some structure that can contain the temp and the count, or imply that that the array index is the temp e.g. `tempCounts[9]` is for 9 degrees.

Comment: @ScaryWombat when I get rid of the dots and do 
" System.out.println(numTemps + "  : " + tempCounts[numTemps]); " 
It counts the votes the way I would expect, I'm just trying to get that number to become a number of asterics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all references to `dots` from your code, and change:

```
System.out.println(numTemps + "  : " + dots);
```

to:

```
System.out.println(numTemps + "  : " + "*".repeat(tempCounts[numTemps]));
```

Comment: You RULE! Thank you so much thats exactly what I needed. I knew there was an easier way then a whole other loop or something.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

To multiply text, call `String#repeat`.

```
System.out.println( temp + " : " + "*".repeat( votes ) );
```

## `String#repeat` to multiply text

Your call to `+=` *adds* text, but does not *multiply* text.

To multiply, call [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) in Java 11+.

```
int votes = 5 ;
String stars = "*".repeat( votes ) ;
```

Result.

```
*****
```

### Example app

You did not indicate how you represent your votes-per-temperature. So I created a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html).

For simplicity I used the "enhanced for loop" (for-each). No need to keep an index counter in this case here.

The for-each is based on a [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) of keys drawn from the map, via the call to `NavigableMap#navigableKeySet`.

```java
package work.basil.example.stars;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {

        NavigableMap < Integer, Integer > temperatureToVotes =
                new TreeMap <>(
                        Map.of(
                                63 , 1 ,
                                65 , 2 ,
                                68 , 5 ,
                                69 , 3 ,
                                70 , 1 ,
                                72 , 3 ,
                                75 , 2
                        )
                );

        for ( Integer temperature : temperatureToVotes.navigableKeySet() )
        {
            Integer votes = temperatureToVotes.get( temperature );
            String message = temperature.toString().concat( " : " ).concat( "*".repeat( votes ) );
            System.out.println( message );
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
63 : *
65 : **
68 : *****
69 : ***
70 : *
72 : ***
75 : **
```

Comment: Where would I put that in my code above?

Comment: @JohnnyRinaldo I added an example app.

Comment: Not gonna lie I understand your new example considerably less than the last one. 

The votes are individual instances of integers in an array. So for example if 68 has 5 votes, then it appears in the array of all the votes 5 times.

Comment: @JohnnyRinaldo You should edit the Question to explain that.